UV map desasterously misplaced
I hope you can help me with this model. I try to texture paint some shading on it but I seem to have destroyed the UVmap.. I checked the normals orientation and tried using smart UV unwraping or Unwrapping, I made a new texture, checked overlays.. When I used the grid texture I saw that the whole thing is horribly distorted and looks nothing like the uv map on the left. Even if I try to correct the left side map nothing changes on the model.. Now I'm left wondering why they differ and what I just don't seem to understand.
If somebody can help me out it would be highly appreciated!


Hello maybe you have 2 UV maps? Check the Data Panel > UV Maps?

You got a "pinned" UV map/image there. Maybe you're not looking at the correct UV map after all.

If you happen to have a disastrously misplaced UV map a good solution for that is to just create a good one instead.
You can delete the UV map and create a new one:

All UV maps the mesh has are listed there, so if you for some reason expect the mesh to have a different one, it could be there as well. You can have multiple UV maps and choose which one to use for specific textures with UV Map node in the Shader nodes.
In any case, if you create a new UV map it's empty and you have to create the UVs in it. The most common way is to unwrap. That workflow consists of 2 very simple steps:

Select some edges in edit mode and mark them as seams. It's very important to think well about how the surface will be unwrapped and where you want the seams.



Select all(or just the part of your model that you want to unwrap) and unwrap. In current Blender version 4.3 there is now a choice of 3 unwrapping algorithms that use seams:


Try all 3 algorithms, see what works best for your case. There is no single algorithm that works best for absolutely everything and in different situations you may want to use different ones. Choose one based on your model and circumstances.
After unwrapping you can adjust the UVs in the UV Editor and lay out the islands in a way that makes sense to you for the texture. It's always a good idea not to waste texture space and try to fit them in a way that they take up as much of the area as possible. You can also pin UVs in the UV Editor( P  with some UV points selected). Pinned UVs will not be altered if you unwrap again and the unwrap algorithms will try to adjust everything else to the pinned UVs remaining in place.  Alt  +  P  unpins selected UVs. There are a few other useful features in the UV Editor:

You should really get yourself familiar with all of them. There aren't that many anyway. Don't forget you can use proportional editing and even some sculpting brushes as well:
 

Woah, I didn't know that one object can have several UVs! That helped so much!! I have selected the correct UV now and it is shown on the model. Unfortunately I have another problem now. When trying to paint on the 3D Model in the Viewport nothing is visible in the material vp, but the paint shows in solid mode ... on the other hand I can paint on the UV and it shows on the model, but I have to paint on the model itself to make small shading edits.. Also the paint I trial painted on the UV doesn't show in rendered view in Cycles .. do you have an idea why that is? Thank you for the help! :)

If you have more questions, ask them as separate questions. Search if they have been asked before though. I am sure there must be answers about texture painting here already.

okay, thank you!

Mind the terminology as well. The term "UVs" usually refers to UV vertices. Objects may have multiple UV Maps that have many UVs each.

@AnimBlenderino if Martynas' answer was correct, mark it as such

Thank you guys! The double UV maps you mentioned were the first problem and I also didn't know I have to save the texture image before switching views. Now it shows in all and everything works awesome! I marked the message as correct now, as it was my first post I didn't see I could and I will mind the difference between UV and UV maps. Thanks a lot!
